# Retrieve first result from API

Tags: php

Here is my `get_first` method attempt, but I'm getting a `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array` error:

```
    public function get_first($path, $args = [])
{
    foreach ($data as $key => $single) {
        if ($single[0]['email'] === $args['email_address']) {
            $output = $single[0]['email'];
        }
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Which returns the first result as shown here:

```
object(stdClass)[407]
  public 'id' => int 6
  public 'email' => string 'a@abc.com' (length=25)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get the property of std class object you need to use arrow, but here you were trying to get the property as associative array.

```
foreach ($data as $key => $single) {
    if ($single->email == $args['email_address']) {
        $output = $single;
    }
}
```

Comment: So when I removed the [0] it works, but I also am unable to match the email_address to the email.

Comment: @SLE updated my answer, please check if it works now

Comment: this worked great! Apologies for not circling back on this, but I just upvoted the answer - Could you please upvote my question if it made sense?